# Number of cookies mismatches in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

In my site (having one 1st party & two 3rd party cookies) cookies in Chrome using below two methods:

**1st:** **Site information** and it shows **38 Cookies** in use.

[image: site information]

**2nd: Inspect -> Application** and it was **30 cookies** names there.

[image: inspect application]

Now the **problems** are:

1. **Why the number of cookies differs in both places.**
2. **If I reload the page the cookies count changes, why?**

Comment: Looks like a bug in the site info UI - if I click "Cookies" and expand them, I see the same actual amount as shown in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see the same as him, it is different, I think this has to do with IFrame's, cookies that have been set later or removed immidiatly after load of page. Removed immidiatly after load of page might be the best shot here... (Maybe the debugger updates the cookies and the other does not (you might wanna check that))

Comment: @wOxxOm What does it mean, is Chrome unable to fetch correct information?

Comment: It means that Chrome is like any other program that may have incorrect code, aka a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Chrome (site information) sums Cookies, Local Storage and Session Storage records.